Assigning mass equally around a wheel
I need to fit 25 similar parts around a wheel in 25 fixed, equally spaced locations. The parts are of similar but not equal mass - about 1% total variation. Is there a formula (or better still a spreadsheet!) I can use to calculate the optimal placement of each part to keep the wheel in balance?

How are you defining "balance"?

Do you mean that you have a regular 25-gon with center $O$ and that each vertex $V_k$ is massive with mass say $1+\epsilon_k$. If such is the case, just check that $\sum \epsilon_k \vec{OV_k}=0$.

One formalization would be: given a set of $n$ masses, place them equally spaced around the unit circle so as to minimize the norm of the center of mass.  So you're optimizing over the choice of permutation.  This version has been asked before, see Finding the optimal placement of weights on a circle.

@JeanMarie I think the $\epsilon_k$ are known and what's wanted is the permutation that assigns them to positions so as to get the best balance - however that's defined. It mght be the minumum length of the sum you suggest.
